# How can i save a image in my server using jquery in asp classic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to save a image that the user upload.I already have the file in base64 string and have in a FileReader var ,how can i save it in a folder?

Jquery Code:

```
$("#picture").on('change',function(){ 
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        $('.frame-image').css('background-image', "url('"+fr.result+"')");  
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Imagem</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture" id="picture" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame-image" style="background-image: url('../img/frames/placeholder-square.svg');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send the contents of the variable to the server:

```
$.post("path/to/save.asp", { imagestring : fr.readAsText() });
```

On the server side, you'll retrieve the imagestring value from the form, and save it to a file.  (You'll need to try different formatting and conversion options until you get something that saves correctly.

string data = Request.Form("imagestring");

Use [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx) to save the file.

Sorry for the lack of code; it's been a long time since I needed to use Classic ASP.